# Seeding Related Data with EF 6

Tags: entity-framework

I'm looking for some simple advice, I just cannot seem to get the answer (or I don't know how to ask the right question).

Here goes, I have 2 classes used to build a db using EF with Code first approach:

```
  public class Dealer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DealerName { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
 public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public Dealer Dealer { get; set; }

}
```

So, EF creates a DB for me, and in the Products table also creates a "Dealer-ID (FK, int, null)" field so that Products can be related to Dealers.

So, in order to have a nice test application (which this is), I want to Seed the DB with some info.

I create some Dealers:

```
 context.Dealers.AddOrUpdate(
                p => p.DealerName,
                new Models.Dealer { DealerName = "Los Angeles" },
                new Models.Dealer { DealerName = "New York" },
                new Models.Dealer { DealerName = "London" },
                new Models.Dealer { DealerName = "Quebec" },
                new Models.Dealer { DealerName = "Gothenburg" }
            );
```

and now I want to create some products, and relate them to Dealers at the same time. Ordinarily, I would simply put an index value into the Dealer_ID Foreign Key field in the products table, but, since this wasn't in my models class in the first place, it's not available.
I do however have a List available.

Like this:

```
 context.Products.AddOrUpdate(
            p => p.ProductName,
            new Models.Product { ProductName = "Electronics",
                        Dealer = ???????
            },
            new Models.Product
            {
                ProductName = "Sushi",
                Dealer = new Models.Dealer { DealerName = "Johannesburg" }
            }
            );
```

I successfully add a Product "Sushi", and relate it to a new dealer called "Johannesburg", but, how do I add "Electronics" to the existing dealer "London" for example. What goes in the ?????? so that I can reference an existing dealer??

I can't create new dealers for each product, since that defeats the purpose of relating the tables in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Save the dealers in a `List<Dealer>` (or an array) and set the `Dealer` property in a `Product` using the specific index in the list:

```
var dealers =new List<Models.Dealer>(){
             new Models.Dealer { DealerName = "Los Angeles" },
             new Models.Dealer { DealerName = "New York" },
             new Models.Dealer { DealerName = "London" },
             new Models.Dealer { DealerName = "Quebec" },
             new Models.Dealer { DealerName = "Gothenburg" },
             new Models.Dealer { DealerName = "Johannesburg" }
        };

context.Dealers.AddOrUpdate(p => p.DealerName,dealers.ToArray());

context.Products.AddOrUpdate(
        p => p.ProductName,
        new Models.Product { ProductName = "Electronics", Dealer = dealers[2]},
        new Models.Product { ProductName = "Sushi",Dealer = dealers[5]});

context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what octaviocci is getting at is that you need to provide a value for the Dealer property. Entity Framework will take care of populating the Dealer_Id. That being said, I would recommend storing any of the dealers which you wish to reference in individual variables so that your code is more resilient to change and clear to read.

```
var laDealer = new Models.Dealer { DealerName = "Los Angeles" };
var nyDealer = new Models.Dealer { DealerName = "New York" };
var londonDealer = new Models.Dealer { DealerName = "London" };
var quebecDealer = new Models.Dealer { DealerName = "Quebec" };
var gothenburgDealer = new Models.Dealer { DealerName = "Gothenburg" };
var johannesburgDealer = new Models.Dealer { DealerName = "Johannesburg" };
var dealers =new List<Models.Dealer>(){
         laDealer,
         nyDealer,
         londonDealer,
         quebecDealer,
         gothenburgDealer,
         johannesburgDealer
    };
context.Dealers.AddOrUpdate(p => p.DealerName,dealers.ToArray());
```

I would also recommend adding an additional save between the dealer creation and the products creation.

```
context.SaveChanges();
context.Products.AddOrUpdate(
        p => p.ProductName,
        new Models.Product { ProductName = "Electronics", Dealer = londonDealer},
        new Models.Product { ProductName = "Sushi",Dealer = johannesburgDealer}
    );  
context.SaveChanges();
```

I recommend this because my experience has shown that in some cases the save for the dealers may not execute before the product save. This can cause a foreign key conflict. (This might only apply when the foreign key column is non-nullable, but I'm not certain.)

Comment: This looks like a pretty good solution as well. I like this one. +1

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at these type of solutions, but I kept on thinking "it shouldn't be this complex".

I solved it eventually, and here's what I did:

You basically Instantiate a particular Dealer first, then add all the products to it...

```
  Models.Dealer dealer1 = context.Dealers.Where(e => e.DealerName == "Los Angeles").First();
        context.Products.AddOrUpdate(
            p => p.ProductName,
            new Models.Product
            {
                ProductName = "Electronics",
                Dealer = dealer1
            },
             new Models.Product
             {
                 ProductName = "Gourmet Food",
                 Dealer = dealer1
             },
             new Models.Product
             {
                 ProductName = "Sushi",
                 Dealer = dealer1
             },
             new Models.Product
             {
                 ProductName = "Beach Wear",
                 Dealer = dealer1
             }, new Models.Product
             {
                 ProductName = "Fast Cars",
                 Dealer = dealer1
             });
```

It is important to note though, that if you're doing this, by the time the Products are to be added, there will be no Dealers committed to the DB yet, so you need to actually do this:

```
  protected override void Seed(RelatedDataExample.Models.myContext context)
    {


        context.Dealers.AddOrUpdate(
                p => p.DealerName,
                new Models.Dealer { DealerName = "Los Angeles" },
                new Models.Dealer { DealerName = "New York" },
                new Models.Dealer { DealerName = "London" },
                new Models.Dealer { DealerName = "Quebec" },
                new Models.Dealer { DealerName = "Gothenburg" }
            );

        context.SaveChanges();

        Models.Dealer dealer1 = context.Dealers.Where(e => e.DealerName == "Los Angeles").First();
        context.Products.AddOrUpdate(
            p => p.ProductName,
            new Models.Product
            {
                ProductName = "Electronics",
                Dealer = dealer1
            },
             new Models.Product
             {
                 ProductName = "Gourmet Food",
                 Dealer = dealer1
             },
             new Models.Product
             {
                 ProductName = "Sushi",
                 Dealer = dealer1
             },
             new Models.Product
             {
                 ProductName = "Beach Wear",
                 Dealer = dealer1
             }, new Models.Product
             {
                 ProductName = "Fast Cars",
                 Dealer = dealer1
             });

        Models.Dealer dealer2 = context.Dealers.Where(e => e.DealerName == "Quebec").First();
        context.Products.AddOrUpdate(
            p => p.ProductName,
            new Models.Product
            {
                ProductName = "Maple Syrup",
                Dealer = dealer2
            },
             new Models.Product
             {
                 ProductName = "Warm Jackets",
                 Dealer = dealer2
             },
             new Models.Product
             {
                 ProductName = "Fermented Fish Head",
                 Dealer = dealer2
             });

    }
```

To my simple mind, this was the simplest solution.
Anyone have a better way?
Cheers
JohannS